# How to change default network with Google-Provided Dataflow Template

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to setup a Dataflow job using the google provided template `PubSub to BigQuery`. However I am getting this error on start up:

```
Message: The resource 'projects/my-project/global/networks/default' was not found
```

I think the google provided template is hardcoded to use the `default` network. The error goes away if I create a `default` network in automatic mode. But we can't have a `default` network in production.

The document [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params) mentions a `network` parameter. I tried adding an additional parameter called `network` from GCP console UI passing in our custom network name. But I am getting this error:

```
The template parameters are invalid.
```

Is there any way I can tell the Google provided Dataflow template to use my custom network(created in manual mode) instead of the `default`? What are my options here?

Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently supported for Dataflow pipelines created from a template. For now, you can either run the template in the default VPC network, or submit a Dataflow pipeline using the Java or Python SDK and specify the `network` pipeline option.

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting the same error if I add `subnetwork` as 'Additional Parameters' in the Create Job page. This is what I see in my browser network console: `{
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.dataflow.v1beta3.InvalidTemplateParameters",
        "parameterViolations": [
          {
            "parameter": "subnetwork",
            "description": "Unrecognized parameter"
          }
        ]
      }`

Comment: Oops, my original answer was incorrect. Upon further inspection, it seems that specifying network/subnetwork is unsupported for template pipelines. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use gcloud beta command `gcloud beta dataflow jobs run` as explained here in [gcloud beta dataflow jobs run](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/dataflow/jobs/run).
It supports more parameters like `[--network=NETWORK]` and `[--subnetwork=SUBNETWORK]` which are useful for your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

The Issue and the solution provided here is 5 years ago. it is not hardcoded to the default network anymore. You can specify your custom network and subnetwork in the Console and gcloud CLI.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).